# Open an URL on a client when it connects to a wifi network - how?

Tags: router, wifi, captive-portal

An enterprise has a "guest" WiFi that's password protected (so no open access) that their clients can use to reach the Internet. They also want to make it so that when someone connects, they'd get their browser open and a certain (promo/local) URL resource loaded. I am now reading about captive portals that are designed to open an auth page, but this URL is more of an ad page than an auth page. So, is there any kind of an alternate method to make them visit the URL, and then be free to close it and roam the Internet?

Comment: AFAIK a captive portal is the only way to get devices to open an URL when they connect to a WiFi network. But you're not required to set up authentication on that URL, right? You can also place your add there instead with a tick box/link that they accept fair usage terms and waive responsibility etc. etc.

Comment: @HBruijn I started wondering about how to auto-authorize users once they get that URL displayed, digging deep into RADIUS settings and such. Okay then